# read each line one at a time in csh

Tags: shell-script, csh

In bash, code like this will read each line in a file one at a time:

```
while IFS=$'\r' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    something
done < "to-read-file"
```

When the code is running, as long as it hasn't reached the final line of the to-read-file, I can add lines to the end of the to-read-file and the code will continue working on new added lines.

I need your help for a similar code in csh. Currently the code I am using under csh is like this:

```
foreach line (cat to-read-file) 
(do things) 
end
```

It will read all the lines at once. Once the code is running, the new lines added to the to-read-file will not be read. Any idea how I can make it read the line once at a time? For some reason I have to work under csh for this case.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `csh` doesn't have a `read` built-in, or anything similar.  BTW, assuming you meant `foreach line (\`cat to-read-file\`) ` (with backticks), the `cat` is executed only once to construct the list of words for the `foreach`, it exits as soon as it finishes reading the file.   `csh` has many flaws and is [not suitable for scripting](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/csh) - it's not even a good interactive shell (it had some good features for its time when it was first release in 1978, but bourne shells have long since surpassed them).

Comment: btw, the sh `read` loop will also terminate when it reaches EOF but it's not so obvious because it's reading the file one line at a time.  Also BTW, relying on this is introducing a deliberate race-condition to your code - if you want to continuously read a file as it is growing, use `tail -f` in either a pipe or a process substitution.    Finally, if you don't want to switch to a bourne shell, use a language like `awk` or `sed` or `perl` to process your file (I'd recommend this in sh too because while sh is capable of doing this, it's a very slow and inefficient tool for the job).

Comment: @cas thank you very much. As I said I have to deal with csh in this case. Can you instruct me how to use `awk` or `sed` or `perl` as you suggested to read in lines one at a time in a csh script?

Answer (score -1):

```csh
set v = `cat file`
@ i = 1
while ( $i <= $#v )
    echo $v[$i]
    @ i = $i + 1
end
```

Comment: add line breaks - it removed them

Comment: Welcome on U&L! The box in which you compose questions and answers gives you a fair amount of information on how to format posts, including code. Particularly, please have a look at the question mark icon in the upper right corner of that box.